# How to solve $c \arccos(x)=x$ for the $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

The equation

$$c \arccos(x)=x$$

certainly has at least one solution for every real number in range $[-1,1]$, because the $[-1,1]$ is the domain of the $\arccos$. For example, if the $x=0.5$, then $c=0.5/\arccos(0.5) \approx 0.4775$.

The equation might be transformed to
$$
\arccos(x)=x/c \\
\cos(\arccos(x))=\cos(x/c) \\
x=\cos(x/c)
$$
but now what? 
The goal is to solve the equation for the $x$, not the $c$.

Thank You.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zqnstncghr $$\text{play c as slider}$$

Comment: In order to solve for $x$ and "not the c", you need to specify $c$.   See this introduction to [posting here with mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: The $c$ is meant to be a constant that is meant to be part of the expression that describes the $x$ at the solution. One of the ideas that I actually came here to post as a comment is that due to the conditionality of the solution, id est the domain of the $acos$, may be the $x$ could be replaced by some arbitrary function of $x$ that has a range that matches with the $acos$ domain, the $[-1,1]$. For example, may be the initial $acos(x)=\frac{x}{c}$ might be replaced with $acos(\frac{2-cos(x)}{3})=\frac{\frac{2-cos(x)}{3}}{c}$ I don't know.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the link to the LaTeX comments. I did not know that it's possible to use those here.

Answer (score 3):

As already said in comments, you will need a numerical method to solve for $x$ the equation $$x=\cos \left(\frac{x}{c}\right)$$

You can also approximate the solution using 
$$\cos(t) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4t^2}{\pi ^2+t^2}\qquad (-\frac \pi 2 \leq t\leq\frac \pi 2)$$ and solve the cubic equation 
$$x^3+4 x^2+\pi ^2 c^2 x-\pi ^2 c^2=0$$ which will show only one real root outside the range $$-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{13 \sqrt{65}-83}{8}}}{\pi } \leq c \leq \frac{\sqrt{\frac{13 \sqrt{65}-83}{8}}}{\pi }$$

For example, using $c=\frac 12$, the "good" solution of the above cubic is $x \approx 0.514891$ while the "exact" solution would be $x\approx 0.514933$.

Using $c=2$, the real solution of the above cubic is $x\approx 0.899569$ while the "exact" solution would be $x\approx 0.900367$.

Nevertheless, to polish the root, you need to use Newton method (or Halley or Householder) or even something like bisection.

**Edit**

Assuming $c>0$, it seems that the very empirical model 
$$x=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i c^i}{1+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i c^i}$$ (in which we shall impose $\color{red}{a_1=\frac \pi 2}$ to match exactly the slope at the origin and $\color{red}{a_n=b_n}$ to respect the asymptote) can do a pretty good job.

For example, using $n=4$ and $1000$ equally spaced for $0 \leq x \leq 0.999$ (this corresponds to $0 \leq c \leq 22.3365$) we get $R^2>0.999999$ and the following results
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a_2 & 1.51116 & 0.00848 & \{1.49452,1.52779\} \\
 a_3 & 0.95188 & 0.00815 & \{0.93588,0.96788\} \\
 a_4 & 0.16484 & 0.00518 & \{0.15468,0.17501\} \\
 b_1 & 1.95839 & 0.00537 & \{1.94785,1.96892\} \\
 b_2 & 1.60644 & 0.01077 & \{1.58529,1.62758\} \\
 b_3 & 0.95123 & 0.00817 & \{0.93519,0.96726\} \\
\end{array}
$$

For the worked examples, it would give $x=0.514929$ and $x=0.900368$.

Using these estimates, Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.51492900000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.51493326468407799198 \\
 2 & 0.51493326466112941380
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.90036800000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.90036722259401261506 \\
 2 & 0.90036722258974714607
\end{array}
\right)$$ which are the solutions for twenty significant figures.

For very large values of $c$, we could use Taylor expansions around $x=1^-$ and get $$\frac{x}{\cos ^{-1}(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-x}}-\frac{13 \sqrt{1-x}}{12 \sqrt{2}}+O\left((1-x)^{3/2} \right)$$ leading to $$x\approx \frac{1}{13}+\frac{24}{169}c\,\sqrt{36 c^2+78} -\frac{144 }{169}c^2$$

For $c=50$, the above approximation would give $x\approx 0.9998000866198$ while the exact solution would be                   $x\approx 0.9998000866186$.

For infinitely large values of $c$, we can expand again the above result and get $$x\approx 1-\frac{1}{2 c^2}+\frac{13}{24 c^4}-\frac{845}{1152 c^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{c^8}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

One cannot solve this algebraically, but you can solve it numerically. For example, one could implement a recursive approach:

$$x_0=0.9\\x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n/c)\\x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$$

(The $0.9$ can actually be replaced with an real number, however, the root is generally near $0.9$)

For an example of this, see here: https://repl.it/LHoa/8

One might notice that $\cos(t/c)$ has a negative slope at $t=x$, where $x$ is the solution you seek. Thus, one could accelerate the convergence in an Euler-sum manner:

$$x_0=0.9\\x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n/c)\\a(n,0)=x_n\\a(n,k+1)=\frac{a(n,k)+a(n+1,k)}2\\x=\lim_{n\to\infty}a(n,k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}a(n,k)$$

For an example of this, see here: https://repl.it/LHoa/7

Since this is a recursive formula, we can further improve the convergence by looping initial values through: https://repl.it/LHoa/10

Comment: Currently I suspect that some kind of numerical solution is the solution that I have to resort to, but I'm a bit stubborn. Namely, before astronomers learned to use the arithmetic mean for averaging out their measurement results, for example, when measuring the "diameter" of the sun, they just agreed to pick one measurement from their series. It seems to me that those conditional cases like the lack of continuity of the absolute value function, the abs(..), might also have some smarter solution than the numerical one. Your answer is probably the one that I'm looking for, but let's see, where..

Comment: @MartinVahi If you want to pick approximations off, use$$\cos(x/c)\approx1-\frac{x^2}{2c^2}$$and apply the quadratic formula.

Comment: Or, since we know that $x\approx1$ for $c>1$, we can use Taylor approximations:$$\cos(x/c)\approx\cos(1/c)-\frac{\sin(1/c)}c(x-1)-\frac{\cos(1/c)}{2c^2}(x-1)^2$$

Comment: ...but let's see, where people's thoughts move, before I just accept the "status quo". I mean, this idea that there's no derivative of the abs function at point 0 is so classical that at least someone must have some clever idea, how to get by without making 2 branches of the calculation. In the case of the current question there are 3 regions on the $\R$, the $(-\infty , -1)$, $[-1,1]$, $(1,\infty)$. Generally the math that solves equations assumes a continuous domain. The practicality of finding some general way to "solve" those noncontinuous domain based eq. is software devel. simplification

Comment: I'm not sure what continuous domains and assumptions have to do here. In the case of $c=1$, you get the [Dottie number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html), which is of non-trivial nature.

Comment: I like Your answer, thank You for that, but as I'm also trying to gather a set of different ideas and approaches before practically semi-randomly "accepting" one solution, I'll leave my question to be open for a day or so.

Comment: @MartinVahi. I do not think that the question should be closed. Other people would be interested by the problem, related comments and answers.